# Understanding .git/config's 'remote' and 'branch' sections

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote, git-config, git-fetch

Here's the contents of the `remote` and `branch` sections of my `.git/config` file.

> ```
> [remote "origin"]  
>     url = https://EvanAad@bitbucket.org/EvanAad/bitbucketstationlocations.git  
>     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
> [branch "master"]  
>     remote = origin  
>     merge = refs/heads/master
> ```

What is the meaning and purpose of the contents of these sections, in particular the `fetch` and `merge` subsections? How is this information used by Git to guide its operation?

Comment: You can read all this in the documentation...

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: @Stony: I don't understand the documentation. I was hoping for a clearer explanation.

Comment: @Rene: Seems to me that the docs on git-config splains all the ways you can use git-config to list and manipulate the git config file - but nothing about what the various contents cause in reference to git behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its called refspec.
Its the mechmism that git is using to "talk" to the remote server and to map local branches to remote branches.

#### Refspecs

**A refspec maps a branch in the local repository to a branch in a remote repository.**
This makes it possible to manage remote branches using local Git commands and to configure some advanced git push and git fetch behavior.

A refspec is specified as `[+]<src>:<dst>`. The `<src>` parameter is the source branch in the local repository, and the `<dst>` parameter is the destination branch in the remote repository.
**The optional `+` sign is for forcing the remote repository to perform a non-fast-forward update**.

Refspecs can be used with the git push command to give a different name to the remote branch. For example, the following command pushes the master branch to the origin remote repo like an ordinary git push, but it uses qa-master as the name for the branch in the origin repo. This is useful for QA teams that need to push their own branches to a remote repo.

```
git push origin master:refs/heads/qa-master
```

**By adding a few lines to the Git configuration file, you can use refspecs to alter the behavior of git fetch.**

By default, `git fetch` fetches all of the branches in the remote repository. The reason for this is the following section of the `.git/config` file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git@github.com:mary/example-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The `fetch` line tells git fetch to **download all of the branches** from the origin repo.
But, some workflows don’t need all of them. For example, many continuous integration workflows only care about the master branch. To fetch only the master branch, change the fetch line to match the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git@github.com:mary/example-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

You can also configure git push in a similar manner. For instance, if you want to always push the master branch to qa-master in the origin remote (as we did above), you would change the config file to:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git@github.com:mary/example-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/qa-master
```

**Refspecs give you complete control over how various Git commands transfer branches between repositories**.

They let you **rename** and **delete** branches from your local repository, `fetch/push` to branches with different names, and configure git push and git fetch to work with only the branches that you want.

Comment: Suppose the `fetch` ref spec is `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. If the remote repository has a branch named `mybranch`, and my local repository does not have a remote tracking branch by the same name, will a remote tracking branch by this name be created, or will an error be reported?

Comment: It will create new branch if it does not exist but if you are using git v2.X and you did not changed the default fetch refspec you will be able to **push** only to the same branch.

Comment: And what if, conversely, my local repository has a remote tracking branch by the name `origin/mybranch` that was created by a previous `fetch`, but in the meanwhile the branch `mybranch` has been deleted on the remote. What will happen in the wake of a `fetch`, given the refspec mentioned in my previous comment? Will the local `origin/mybranch` be deleted?

Comment: If a branch is deleted you can update your local repo with `git fetch --all --prune` it will delete the local undeleted branches. if you try to push deleted branch to the remote it will be created on the remote again

Comment: @CodeWizard could you please format this line - `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`? I can't as it's not enough characters.

Answer (score 28):

## TL;DR summary

Overall, we're interested in two or three things:

1. If you run `git fetch` with no additional arguments, what happens?
2. If you run `git merge` or `git rebase` with no additional arguments, what happens?
3. If you run `git pull` with no additional arguments, what happens?

The short answer to question #1 is: Git picks one of your *remotes* to fetch from, and then fetches from that remote.  The remote Git picks is from the `remote = name` setting under the `[branch]` section.  If there isn't any such setting, Git uses `origin`.

The answer to question #2 is: Git picks some name to use, as if you had run `git merge name` or `git rebase name`.  The *`name`* is *based on* the `merge = ref` setting under the `[branch]` section—but the way this works is somewhat obscure: if this same section says, for instance, `remote = origin` and `branch = refs/heads/master`, the name Git picks to use is not `master` but rather `origin/master`.  If it says `remote = origin` and `branch = develop`, the name Git picks is `origin/develop`, and so on.

(While this looks very straightforward, the actual mapping inside Git is rather tricky: if the section says `remote = .` and `branch = master`, the name is `master`, not `./master`, for instance.  If you set up unusual fetch refspecs, even more weirdness can happen.  This answer does not cover this last case at all.)

The answer to question #3 is in some ways the easiest: `git pull` simply runs `git fetch` first, then—provided that succeeds—one of the other two commands, `git merge` or `git rebase`, so you really only have to look at questions 1 and 2.

## Long

The `merge` entry under each `branch` section is, I think, the least obvious.  The Git documentation keeps it a bit obscure.  Let's cover the others first.

#### Settings under a `[remote "..."]` section

There are many possible settings.  In general, you do not have to set any of them with `git config` directly—almost all of them have wrapper commands to set them in a more "user friendly" manner.  That includes both of the settings you see here.  It's rare to want to change these, either.

The `remote` section for each named remote, such as `origin`, lists the URL for `git fetch` (and optionally a separate push URL for `git push`, and other `remote.*` configuration items as [described in the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)).  It also has one or more `fetch` lines which supply the default *refspec* arguments for `git fetch` from that remote.

That is, if you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

Git will look up `remote.origin.url` to see where to connect, then connect there, then retrieve references based on all the `remote.origin.fetch` entries.  The default that you see here:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

tells Git to copy *all* branches<sup>1</sup> from the remote, renaming them to an `origin/`-prefixed remote-tracking branch<sup>2</sup> in your own repository, so:

```
git fetch origin
```

basically fetches everything.  (The leading `+` says that Git should do this regardless of whether the remote-tracking branch update is a fast-forward operation.  That is, it's like using `--force`, but without having to specify `--force`.)

On the other hand, if you run:

```
git fetch origin a:b c:d
```

Git will *completely ignore* all the `fetch =` lines, retrieving only references `a` and `c` from the remote, writing them to references `b` and `d` in your repository.  (And since this has neither `+` nor `--force`, none of these will be force-updated—though in most cases that makes no difference anyway.)

---

<sup>1, 2</sup> A *reference* is a generic term that covers both branches *and* tags (and more things as well).  Branch names like `master` are just short-hand for references that begin with `refs/heads/`.  Remote-tracking branch names like `origin/master` are just short-hand for references that begin with `refs/remotes/`.  Note that the `origin/` part comes from the `fetch =` line—but for all this to work the way it is supposed to, that line *must* match the name of the remote in the square brackets.

---

#### Settings under a `[branch "..."]` section

There are many possible settings.  In general, you do not have to set any of them with `git config` directly—almost all of them have wrapper commands to set them in a more "user friendly" manner.  That includes both of the settings you see here.  It's not that rare to want to change one or both of them, using a command we will see in a moment.

The `remote` part is pretty clear on its own, though: it means that if you are on branch `master` and run `git fetch` without giving a remote name at all, Git should fetch from the remote named `origin`.

The `merge` part is the tricky one.  It lists the name of a branch *as seen on the remote*.  Note that when we run `git fetch origin`, we tell our Git to call up another Git, find *the other* Git's `master`, and copy that into our repository but call it `origin/master`.  And yet ... this `merge` line says `merge = refs/heads/master`.  Shouldn't it say: `merge = refs/remotes/origin/master`?

It probably should—but this setting predates the very invention of remotes in the first place.  So it doesn't; instead, it lists the full name of the reference *as it appears on the remote*.

This setting is what gets used if you run `git merge` or `git rebase` without providing a branch name to merge or rebase-upon.  Git runs the name through the mappings provided by the `fetch =` line for the remote, to figure out that it should merge with `origin/master`, for instance.

This setting is also used by the `git pull` convenience command, which is effectively<sup>3</sup> the same as running `git fetch` followed by running `git merge`.

You might want to *change* one or both of these.  For instance, if you create a new local branch `feature/tall`, it may have *no* `branch.feature/tall.remote` and `branch.feature/tall.merge` settings at all.

Since you just created this branch, there is no `origin/feature/tall`.  The Git over at `origin` does not have `feature/tall` yet, so you do not have a copy of it.

Then you `git push origin feature/tall:feature/tall` to have your Git call up `origin`'s Git and have their Git *create* that branch, so that you now *do* have `origin/feature/tall`.  You might want your Git to remember that.

You *could* run two `git config` commands, but instead, you can run one higher level wrapper command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/tall feature/tall
```

This tells your Git to set `branch.feature/tall.remote` to `origin`, and `branch.feature/tall.merge` to `refs/heads/feature/tall` (that being the name on `origin`).

You can combine the `git push` and the `git branch --set-upstream-to` steps using `git push -u`, which is even better, but the point here remains: you use a wrapper to get *both* values set at once, since setting only one value is not that useful.<sup>4</sup>

The special remote name `.` means *this repository* (as opposed to some remote repository).  If the `[branch "xyzzy"]` section says `remote = .` and `branch = refs/heads/whatever`, then branch `xyzzy` has *local* branch `whatever` as its upstream, rather than having, e.g., `origin/whatever` as its upstream.

---

<sup>3</sup>This deliberately glosses over a lot of fiddly details.

<sup>4</sup>Setting just the `remote` part *does* affect a future `git push`, but `git merge` and `git rebase` won't be able to do the remote-tracking branch mapping without both entries.

Comment: The settings under the `branch` section have no effect on a `fetch`; only on `merge` and `pull`, correct?

Comment: Right. (And they only affect `git pull` because it runs `git merge`, or if you configure it to, `git rebase`, although the thing that configures `git pull` *to* run `git rebase` is yet another `branch`-section entry!)

Comment: @torek But yet you write: "The `remote` part is pretty clear on its own, though: [...] Git should fetch from the remote named origin"... It would be nice if you could clear that up.

Comment: @philipp2100: just so I get it right: what's the confusion here? Would it help if I included the actual text, `remote = origin`, here?

Comment: No, the confusing part is that you describe `remote`, which is under the `branch` section, to affect `git fetch` in a certain way, but in the comments you both agree that settings under the `branch` section *wouldn't* affect `git fetch`.

Comment: @philipp2100: ah. The issue here is that the `remote = <name>` tells `git fetch` *which* remote to fetch *from*. It has no effect on the fetching action, though, just on which URL and such get used. To control the fetching *action* from that particular remote—including the URL itself—you have to look in the `[remote]` section. I'll see if I can make that clearer.

Comment: @torek Your latest comment and edit cleared it up, thanks!