# git config default push does not work for remote with name other than origin

Tags: git, key, push, config, default

If I add remote repository address this way and set it as default:

```
git init .

remoteName="origin"
dstUrl='location-of-initialized-bare-repository'
git remote add "$remoteName" "$dstUrl"

git config push.default current

touch masterfile
git add masterfile
git commit -m 'first'
git push


git checkout -b feature
touch feautrefile
git add feautrefile
git commit -m 'second'
git push
```

everything works well.
but when i set remote name differently ie:

```
remoteName="something"
```

> fatal: No configured push destination.

I thought that the name for the remote was arbitrary and could be set to any value without any difference in acting but it seems that for the default remote used for `git push` without any parameters it must be `origin` or I'm missing someting? Perhaps git looks for `origin` by default but in case of different name I need to tell it that the different name is the default?

how to set default remote named differently than `origin`?

The solution should work with new branches created in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a new remote URL/name won't enable a local branch to push to it.

You need to use that new remote at least once with:

```
git push -u newRemoteName myBranch
```

See "[Understanding `.git/config`'s '`remote`' and '`branch`' sections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318586/6309)"

That does set the `branch.myBranch.remote` to `newRemoteName`, which then enable a simple `git push` to work.

The first push worked because it defaults to a remote named (by convention) "`origin`".
See [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_description)

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the `<repository>` argument, `branch.*.remote` configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push.
>   If the configuration is missing, it defaults to `origin`.