# Changing my Git remote origin temporarily

Tags: git

I currently have a repo, but I want to temporarily use another repo to push the changes to and then when I choose to, change back to the other repo and push to that one again (this is due to reasons of access to the main repo).

So I'm wondering, if I want to change the repo the pushes go to, is all I have to do is change the *origin* in my git config file, such as:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:myname/my-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Do I just change this line:

```
url = git@bitbucket.org:myname/my-repo.git
```

...to the new value and then back again to go back to the main repo? ...or is there something else to do and if so, what!?

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case, but personally I'd just set up another remote. You can `git push origin` or `git push whatever` to decide where you're pushing. (Note that you _never_ commit to a remote with Git. Commits always happen locally.)

Comment: @Chris Sorry, my bad. I wasn't thinking, meant pushes go to, not commits. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a distributed version control system, Git allows you to manage multiple remote repositories. If it's just temporary, don't touch your origin - just add a separate remote. And don't bother with editing config files, use the command line:

```
git remote add temp git@bitbucket.org:myname/my-other-repo.git
```

Push to a new remote using:

```
git push temp
```

After access issues are solved synchronize origin:

```
git push origin
```

Read more about `git remote` here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.

Comment: Just tried this and when I did `git push -u temp master` it changed `remote = origin` to `remote = temp` under `[branch "master"]` in the config file. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, it's just a default remote to use if you don't specify it explicitly for git push/pull/fetch. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317872/understanding-git-configs-remote-and-branch-sections) for detailed explanation of what various options in `branch` and `remote` sections mean.

Comment: Great, and thanks for the link, I'm sure it will be helpful! :)

Answer (score 6):

you can push and pull directly to/from a remote repository:

```
git push git@bitbucket.org:myname/my-other-repo.git HEAD:refs/heads/foo
git pull git@bitbucket.org:myname/my-other-repo.git refs/heads/foo
```

Comment: This is exactly what I searched to find, thank you!